# Splitting a premise with conjunction conclusion in Coq

Tags: functional-programming, coq, dependent-type, coq-tactic, ltac

I often have to do "induction loading" to prove goals in Coq, where I prove multiple things simultaneously by induction.

The problem is, I often end up with Inductive Hypotheses of the following form:

```
forall a1 ... an, 
  Premise1 -> Premise2 -> ... Premisek -> 
  Conclusion1 /\ Conclusion2 /\ ... Conclusion_m
```

This is fine, but tactics like `eauto` really don't know how to handle things like this, so it kills automation most of the time.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to automatically break such a premise into `m` different premises, i.e.

```
forall a1 ... an, 
  Premise1 -> Premise2 -> ... Premisek -> 
  Conclusion1
  ...
forall a1 ... an, 
  Premise1 -> Premise2 -> ... Premise_k -> 
  Conclusion_m
```

The main problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to match with an arbitrary length chain of arrows in LTac. I could hard-code up to a certain length, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Additionally, if it were possible to do the dual (i.e. split on all combinations of disjunctions in Premise1 .. Premise_k) that would also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert of Ltac, but I gave it a try and came up with the following tactic.

```
Ltac decomp H :=
  try match type of H with
  context c [?A /\ ?B] =>
    let H' := fresh H in
    let Pa := context c[A] in
    assert (H' : Pa) by (apply H);
    let H'' := fresh H in
    let Pb := context c[B] in
    assert (H'' : Pb) by (apply H);
    clear H;
    rename H' into H;
    rename H'' into H';
    decomp H'
  end.

Tactic Notation "decomp_hyp" hyp(H) := decomp H.
```

`decomp H` searches occurrences of conjunctions in `H`, then decomposes it into `H'` and `H''`, clean the state and calls itself recursively.

On a trivial example, this seems to work.

Comment: Good to learn about `context` and holes! Maybe it should also recursively `decomp H` if the goal is like `((A /\ B) /\ C)`

Comment: I think that adding a second recursive call `decomp H` would be enough. The issue with disjunctions in the premises is more difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (minus the debug printouts)?

```
Ltac foo :=
  match goal with
  |  |- forall q, ?X => 
       let x := fresh in intros x; idtac x q ; (try foo); generalize x as q; clear x

  |  |- ?X -> _ => 
       let x := fresh in intros x; idtac x  ; (try foo); generalize x; clear x

  |  |- _ /\ _ => repeat split
  end; idtac "done".

Goal forall {T} (a1 a2 a3:T) P1 P2 P3 Q1 Q2 Q3, P1 a1 -> P2 a2 -> P3 a3 -> Q1 /\ Q2 /\ Q3.
  foo.
```

This leaves you with the goals

```
3 subgoals (ID 253)

  ============================
  forall (T : Type) (a1 a2 a3 : T) (P1 P2 P3 : T -> Type) (Q1 : Prop),
  Prop -> Prop -> P1 a1 -> P2 a2 -> P3 a3 -> Q1

subgoal 2 (ID 254) is:
 forall (T : Type) (a1 a2 a3 : T) (P1 P2 P3 : T -> Type),
 Prop -> forall Q2 : Prop, Prop -> P1 a1 -> P2 a2 -> P3 a3 -> Q2
subgoal 3 (ID 255) is:
 forall (T : Type) (a1 a2 a3 : T) (P1 P2 P3 : T -> Type),
 Prop -> Prop -> forall Q3 : Prop, P1 a1 -> P2 a2 -> P3 a3 -> Q3
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to be able to split *after* I've invoked the `induction` tactic, so that I get `Q1, Q2, Q3` each as a separate inductive hypothesis.